# Can I get data pertaining to the aggregate in a single query?

Tags: sql

I'd like to get both the minimum value of a particular value, *and* the key of the row that has that minimum value. Currently, I do this as follows:

```
SELECT dates.date AS Date, num_apples.apples AS MinApples FROM
(
    SELECT date, MIN(apples) AS MinApples, apples
    FROM Table
    HAVING MinApples = apples
) AS dates
JOIN
(
    SELECT date, apples
    FROM Table
) AS num_apples
ON (
    dates.date = num_apples.date
);
```

Is there a better way to do this using only "standard" (by which I mean commonly-implemented) SQL?

Comment: this is standard, except for the MinApples alias that you would have to replace by the actual aggregate in the having clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `date` is your key:

```
SELECT qryNumApples.* FROM
(
    SELECT MIN(apples) AS MinApples
    FROM Table
) AS qryMinApples
JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Table
) AS qryNumApples
ON qryMinApples.MinApples= qryNumApples.apples
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is ANSI standard SQL:

```
select *
from (
  select date, 
         apples, 
         min(apples) over () as min_apples
  from the_table
) t
where apples = min_apples;
```

Window functions are available across a wide range of DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

I always did it in this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table
WHERE apples = (SELECT MIN(apples) 
                  FROM the_table);
```

But maybe I'm missing something.